# Android dependency 'androidx.core:core' has different version for the compile (1.0.0) and runtime (1.0.1) classpath

Tags: flutter, dart, barcode-scanner, flutter-dependencies

I recently added one new library to my flutter app. It started showing me an error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
> Android dependency 'androidx.core:core' has different version for the compile (1.0.0) and runtime (1.0.1) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUİLD FAILED in 14s
```

Answer (score 0):

try to go to the dependencies and change the  compile to 1.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Go to gradle.properties under android folder, and add the following piece of code:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Step 2. Now go to build.gradle under android and not under the app->build.gradle. While looking into the file make sure it starts with the word builscript (In this way you can ensure you're at the right build.gradle file.)

Step 3. Ctrl+A everything in that file, note that ctrl+A everything you need to erase off all the content and paste this piece of code:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }

    subprojects {
        project.configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
                if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                        && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                    details.useVersion "27.1.1"
                }

                if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.core'
                        && !details.requested.name.contains('androidx') ) {
                    details.useVersion "1.0.1"
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**A very important point to note is that during the process of compilation, chances are that you will see this warning message in complete red. Please don't get scared of it and let the whole compilation complete, before jumping to any conclusions. Although it comes in red, it won't stop your compilation as you will see in the bottom a turning circle that will show the progress of compilation. Right after that, it will disappear and you will be able to run the App. Here's the warning message:**

> Note:
>   C:\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.12.11\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java
>   uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with
>   -Xlint:deprecation for details. Note: C:\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.12.11\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java
>   uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with
>   -Xlint:unchecked for details. ERROR: [TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${animal.sniffer.version}' Note:
>   C:\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\mlkit-0.15.0\android\src\main\java\com\azihsoyn\flutter\mlkit\MlkitPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with
>   -Xlint:unchecked for details.

And Boom! that's it. Trust me this will definitely solve your problems.

In case you still struggle with any such problems try to implement some of the other solutions mentioned in this [link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27254#issuecomment-553000221) as well.